# NEO4J Query to find all the title of movies that an actor

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Query to find all the title of movies that an actor in **Cloud Atlast** acted in, for each movie title , also return the name of these actors

```
MATCH (m:Movie {title:"Cloud Atlast"})<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p:Person)
RETURN p.name, m.title
```

Kindly tell me what did I missed

Comment: You have a typo in the title - the movie's name is `Cloud Atlas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to extend your pattern out and aggregate the actors per movie:

```
MATCH (:Movie {title:"Cloud Atlas"})<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
RETURN m.title as title, collect(p.name) as actors
```

As you're using the movies graph, we can assume that :ACTED_IN relationships only connect :Person nodes to :Movie nodes, so we can remove the labels from the later parts of the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want :

```
    MATCH (:Movie {title:"Cloud Atlas"})<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(others)
    RETURN m.title as title, collect(others.name) as actors
```